# how to set text shadow with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

I want to let user set text shadow by selecting an offset from one input field, blur from another and color from colorpicker. I am using angular and fabric.js and this is my HTML:

```
  <div class="shadow">
    <div class="slider-input">
      <span>Offset</span>
      <input min="-25" max="25" step="1" type="number" ng-change="text.setShadow('offset', offset)" ng-model="offset" />
    </div>

    <div class="slider-input">
      <span>Blur</span>
      <input min="0" max="25" step="1" type="number" ng-change="text.setShadow('blur', blur)" ng-model="blur" />
    </div>

    <div class="colorpicker">
      <span>Color</span>
      <input ed-color-picker-disabled="{{ !enableOutline }}" ed-color-picker="text.setShadow('shadowcolor', color)" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the controller I have set these default values:

```
$scope.offset = 0;
$scope.blur = 0;
$scope.shadowcolor = '#000';
```

In the service I set this function:

```
 setShadow: function(property, value) {
   var text   = this.getTextObject();
   //   if (value == 'offset') {
  //      text.set('shadow', value + 'px' + ' ' + value + 'px')
  //    }
       console.log("property", property);
       console.log("value", value);

  },
```

The problem is that on press I get only the value of one input field or color, but in order to set shadow I need to know the context too (other values).

How to retrieve all of the values - ofsset input field, blur input field and shadow color all at once so that I could set text shadow?

Comment: Can use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller or directive:

```
$scope.shadow = $scope.offset + "px " + $scope.offset + "px " + $scope.blur + "px " + $scope.color;
```

(retrieving the offset, blur, and color from your ng-models as needed.)

in template:

```
ng-style="{textShadow: shadow}"
```

I don't think you're going to be able to do this cleanly from a service that only receives one of the (color / blur / offset) values at a time.  I guess you could have the service cache each value as it receives each one, and only return the text-shadow css when all three values have been fed to the service -- but that would mean only a single directive could use that service without values leaking across directives. (Honestly, I'm questioning why you're using a service for this in the first place; this seems like functionality that belongs in a directive.)

Comment: Something like this:         $scope.setShadow = function(property, value) {

            var active = canvas.fabric.getActiveObject();

            if (!active.fontFamily) {
                return;
            } else {

            $scope.shadow = $scope.offset + "px " + $scope.offset + "px " + $scope.blur + "px " + $scope.color;
            active.set('shadow', $scope.shadow);
   canvas.fabric.renderAll();

            }
        }; throug controller actually helped. Thanks!